# Accessing elements in panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How do I iterate through this dataframe?  I want to know what the nameis (AAL, AAME, or AACG) and be able to access the everything highlighted in red for name.

[image: Pandas stock dataframe]

Comment: can you copy and paste the data into here with the { } code feature? See the { } button.

Comment: Also, this may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56594197/how-to-access-multi-level-index-in-pandas-data-frame

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the multi-index column. Accessing a multi-index column is pretty the same as the access a column in the general dataFrame. For example, if you want to access `2020-05-21` row in `AAL` then you have to...

```
df['AAL']['Date']['2020-05-21']
```